# Java abstract class advise

Tags: java, static, singleton, abstract

I have several different type of Users (different classes) in my app

```
User1

User2
```

etc...

I want to have an abstract class "User" that joins the same methods for all type of Users
ex: `getId(), getAge()....`

I don't really know how that works but what i want to do is something like :

```
User.setType(2); //a kind a constructor
User.getId()... //etc .. the getId() method of the Users2 class
```

Without having to instantiate the abstract class User

How can I do that ? 
The problem I have is that an abstract class can't have static methods ... and User must be static or a Singleton I don't know what is the best.

could anyone give me some tips ?

Thank you

Comment: An abstract class can have static methods; it just can't have abstract static methods. What are you trying to do? Do you mean that each subtype of User is a singleton? (That is, there's at most one `User1` object; at most one `User2` object; etc.?)

Comment: There would just be one singleton which is "User". It would be instantiated differently depending the situation (it could be a User1 or a User2 etc...). After that there's no way to come back during the app. the User is defined and its methods are proper to its instantiation.

Comment: What's wrong with making `User` abstract, giving it instance methods like `getId`, then having `User1` etc. extend it? Do you need to access `User`'s implementations of methods which its subclasses may have overriden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class User {
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
}


public class User1 extends User { }
public class User2 extends User { }

User user1 = new User1();
user1.getId();
User user2 = new User2();
user2.getId();
```

> Without having to instantiate the abstract class User

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

> User must be static or a Singleton I don't know what is the best.

Even though abstract classes can have static methods, that does not quite make sense (specially when you want an abstract `User` and multiple specific types of `User`s).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really know how that works but what i want to do is something
>   like : ...Without having to instantiate the abstract class User

You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

> The problem I have is that an abstract class can't have static methods

Yes it can.

> and User must be static or a Singleton I don't know what is the best.

Is there only ever one `User` instance?  Your question needs to be refined.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Yes there is only one User instance while the application is running. sorry for my poor english

Comment: No problem.  If there is only one instance use the Singleton pattern.  You can find it on Wikipedia.

Comment: Consider a Singleton pattern that returns the correct type of user through a factory.

Answer (score 0):

filter common methods of **User1** and **User2**.Now Have a abstract class User with common methods like below

`public abstract class User{`

`public void commonmethod1();`

`public void commonmethod2();`

`}`

Now define two User classes User1 and User2 which should have atleast one extra method like below

`public class User1 extends User{`

`public void commonmethod1(){}`

`public void commonmethod2(){}`

`public void extramethod1(){}`

`}`

`public class User2 extends User{`

`public void commonmethod1(){}`

`public void commonmethod2(){}`

`public void extramethod12(){}`

`}`

decide what to do with subclasses,singleton restricts the state of an object and sometimes it is treated as anti pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest thing would be to make `User` and interface and define a factory class. Here's a version (that slightly abuses the notion of "factory class") with the factory as a static class (it could also be defined as a singleton class):

```
public interface User {
    int getId();
}

public class UserFactory() {
    private final User sInstance;

    public static void initFactory(int type) {
        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            sInstance = new User1();
            break;
        case 2:
            sInstance = new User2();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("error message");
        }
    }

    public static User getUser() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Must initialize factory first");
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private static class User1 implements User {
        public int getId() {
            . . .
        }
    }

    private static class User1 implements User {
        public int getId() {
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```